# How to call the property that says that a heuristic is able to find the optimal solution?

Tags: optimization, analysis-of-algorithms

Given a heuristic approach to solving an optimization problem, does there exist a name for the property that says that this heuristic is *able* (but might not be guaranteed) to find the optimal solution? I.e. for search heuristics like local-search-based methods, the optimal solution is guaranteed to be in the search space.

Comment: I would like to know it. There is a problem I started working on fifty years ago (I am still working it). Fourty years ago, I developed a  heuristic approach which we ran zillions of times with full success. The problem is that I cannot prove the solution. And this is an optimization problem.

Comment: So this is every heuristic, except those guaranteed to never find the optimal solution?

Comment: Are you speaking about optimality conditions? Optimality conditions are conditions satisfied by minimizers of given problems. If limit points of a given method satisfy one optimality condition, this means that the method is able to find optimal points. For algorithms, sequential optimality conditions are suitable regarding them. Each algorithm generate a type of sequential optimality condition. Calling optimality conditions a "heuristic" sounds weird, but in practice they are.

Comment: For example, If limit points of a given heuristic satisfy an optimality condition, this heuristic is able to find optimal points. The problem comes when you can't prove that limit points of a given heuristic satisfy a given optimality condition, since this could mean that the heuristic can actually avoid some  "good candidates for optimal points".

Comment: @MarkL.Stone To clarify what I mean, let me give an example. The Parallel Schedule Generation Scheme heuristic, which is used to solve RCPSP, generates non-delay schedules. When minimizing makespan, it is not guaranteed that an optimal solution is contained in the set of non-delay schedules. In other words, PSGS searches in a space that *might* not contain the optimal solution.

On the contrary, Serial SGS generates active schedules. Since it is known that the set of active schedules contains an optimal solution, SSGS searches in a space that contains the optimal solution.